# Moving oldest files first from source to destination

Tags: excel, vba, filesystemobject

I have more than 2000 files in a source which I was moving using the code below. The process was running but today (after two weeks) it gives

> Run Time Error 58" "File Already Exist"

Upon checking there is no such file which is available in source and destination folder and all files names are separate from each other.

Even if both source and destination folders are empty it is giving the same error at the line `Name FromPath & fileName As ToPath & fileName`.

```vb
Function OldestFile(strFold As String) As String
    Dim FSO As Object, Folder As Object, File As Object, oldF As String
    Dim lastFile As Date: lastFile = Now
    Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set Folder = FSO.GetFolder(strFold)
    For Each File In Folder.Files
        If File.DateCreated < lastFile Then
            lastFile = File.DateCreated: oldF = File.Name
        End If
    Next
    OldestFile = oldF
End Function


Sub MoveOldestFile()
    Dim FromPath As String, ToPath As String, fileName As String, limit As Long
    FromPath = "C:\Users\user\Desktop\Source\"
    ToPath = "C:\Users\user\Desktop\Destination\"
    limit = 20
    filesmoved = 0
    fileName = OldestFile(FromPath)
    Do Until fileName = "" Or filesmoved = limit
        If Dir(ToPath & fileName) = "" Then
            Name FromPath & fileName As ToPath & fileName
            filesmoved = filesmoved + 1
        End If
        fileName = OldestFile(FromPath)
    Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: Can you give an example of a filename where this error happens? Could be an issue with short filenames

Comment: file Names are (e.g.)   north East Feb 23, 2023 - In process

Comment: but the issue is even if both (Source and Destination) folders are empty it is still giving the same error at the line   Name FromPath & fileName As ToPath & fileName

Comment: Does it give the error when you rename the *first* file or later?

Comment: No Sir. It starts giving error after moving certain files (e.g. out of 1000 when it moves 20 files it start giving error)

Comment: but now i am emptied both Source and Destination and still it gives the same error :(

Comment: basically the motive is i need to more oldest files first in a bunch like 25 files at a time or 50 files at a time

Comment: Microsoft Scripting Runtime is also activated i do  not understand why it is giving such error

Comment: Such an error, theoretically cannot be raised in any other circumstance, than a file with the same name in the destination folder. When stopped on error, if press `F5` does it move the file? If yes, it may be solved placing a delay.  If not, move the cursor over `fileName` and (visually) see if it exists in destination folder. Hard to believe that it does not exist and that error is raised...

Comment: @FaneDuru let me check and i will revert

Comment: when pressing F5 it still does not move the file, but when i move my cursor over FileName It displays File Name = "Desktop.ini"

Comment: So, you should exclude this name from moving sequence...

Comment: @FaneDuru I cannot change the names of the files I do not have any such file "Desktop.ini"

Comment: `Desktop.Ini` is a (normally hidden) file created automatically by Windows. You need to skip it.

Comment: @FunThomas exactly that could be the reason, how can i skip this

Comment: This Code is the starting code and is very very important for me. After this code there are numerous codes (which i have made with the help of @FaneDuru and everything is stopped in the first step :(

Comment: @FunThomas and FaneDuru i think this is some kind of virus. I believe reinstalling a fresh windows and MS office will resolve the issue

Comment: The ini file is hidden. Now I am driving... no any virys! Windows creates such files.

Comment: thanks sir :) both Faneduru and Funthomas, have a safe drive

Comment: https://www.thewindowsclub.com/desktop-ini-file-windows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cannot say that I understand the logic of your code as at the end it will move *all* files, no matter how old they are, so what do you achieve with the fact that you move the oldest file first?

Anyhow, what you could do is to skip system files (like desktop.ini) by checking the [file attribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/attributes-property)

```
Function OldestFile(strFold As String) As String
    Const ATTR_SYSTEM = 2
    Dim FSO As Object, Folder As Object, File As Object, oldF As String
    Dim lastFile As Date: lastFile = Now
    Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set Folder = FSO.GetFolder(strFold)
    For Each File In Folder.Files
        If (File.Attributes And ATTR_SYSTEM) = 0 And File.DateCreated < lastFile Then
            lastFile = File.DateCreated: oldF = File.Name
        End If
   Next
   OldestFile = oldF
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

change the following line:

```
If Dir(ToPath & fileName) = "" Then
```

to

```
If Dir(ToPath & fileName, 7) = "" Then
```

That line is failing to check for read only, system or hidden files. So your code tries to rename an existing hidden file.

Yo may want to try this variant of your code which should have a better performance in big directories as it does not iterate over the whole directory each time

```
Function OldestFile(strFold As String) As Variant
    Dim FSO As Object, Folder As Object, File As Object, oldF As String
    Dim lastFile As Date: lastFile = Now
    Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set Folder = FSO.GetFolder(strFold)
    Dim myarray As Variant
    If Folder.Files.Count > 0 Then
        ReDim myarray(Folder.Files.Count - 1)
        ix = 0
        For Each File In Folder.Files
            myarray(ix) = Format(File.DateCreated, "YYYYMMDDHHmmSS") & File.Name
            ix = ix + 1
        Next
        For i = LBound(myarray) To UBound(myarray) 'Sort according to date
            For j = i + 1 To UBound(myarray)
                If UCase(myarray(i)) > UCase(myarray(j)) Then
                    Temp = myarray(j)
                    myarray(j) = myarray(i)
                    myarray(i) = Temp
                End If
            Next j
        Next i
    End If
OldestFile = myarray
End Function


Sub MoveOldestFile()
    Dim FromPath As String, ToPath As String, fileName As String, limit As Long
    Dim fileArray As Variant
    FromPath = "C:\Users\user\Desktop\Source\"
    ToPath = "C:\Users\user\Desktop\Destination\"
    limit = 20
    filesmoved = 0
    fileArray = OldestFile(FromPath)
    If Not IsEmpty(fileArray) Then
        ix = 0
        Do Until ix > UBound(fileArray) Or filesmoved = limit
            fileName = Mid(fileArray(ix), 15)
            If Dir(ToPath & fileName, 7) = "" Then
                Name FromPath & fileName As ToPath & fileName
                filesmoved = filesmoved + 1
            End If
            ix = ix + 1
        Loop
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: @Funthomas yes this line has resolved the issue in previous code and is now working perfect for now., Thanks alot , i will check in more details and will update in case of any issue

Comment: Taka a look at the code above to improve your routines